# Best way to add a list of items to a user in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, web-development-server

I want to assign a list of classes(courses) to my users in SQL. Users may have a different number of courses. I've looked around and haven't really found a good way to do it. I don't have a lot of experience in designing databases. 
Each user is simply a row of information on a table with a unique userid. 
Every course in the list needs to have a field for current grade, instructorid, and userid that it belongs to. And maybe more. 
I'm trying to avoid putting it all in 1 row with a bunch of slots and maybe even empty fields. is there a way to assign a whole table to a user? so that each row can be a course?

Comment: Can you show your current structure?

Comment: I think you simply need a couple of tables holding: users, courses, instructors, grades, and subscriptions (when a user subscribes to a course), etc. Whenever there's a link to another table you add a foreign key. So if an user gets a grade the foreign keys in the grades table would be 'userId' and 'courseId'.

Comment: This is really too broad and off-topic for SO, and might be better on dba.stackexchange.com. But you will probably want a user table, a course table, and the a pivot table that will create a many-to-many relationship between the two.

Comment: Whatever you do, _don't_ create a courses column in your users table and fill it with comma separated values.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use **associative table**, which means using **many-to-many** relationship. For example structure like this:

Table
    **Student** (student_id, name, surname)

Table
    **Course** (course_id, name, ..)

Table
    **StudentCourse** (student_id, course_id, teacher_id, date_enrolled, date_passed, grade ...)

The StudentCourse is a connection between Student and Course table, as a student can have many courses and in a course can be enrolled many students.[image]

I would also suggest further reading on database normalisation, associative tables and maybe [this](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/218734758-A-beginner-s-guide-to-many-to-many-relationships) article about many-to-many relationships.